# Nginx "rewrite or return" for Discuz! V 3.1

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I installed Discuz V3.1 on nginx. all the forum is handling right but the UCENTER.
the UCENTER link is return 404 page not found.
its link is appear in the browser like this:

```
http://DOMAIN/uc_server/admin.php/uc_server/admin.php?m=user&a=login&iframe=&sid=
```

which the URI `/uc_server/admin.php/uc_server/` is wrong. the UCENTER URI is `/uc_server/`
or to say it better `htdocs/uc_server` and contains both index.php and forum.php amoung other things.
I want to right a location block for `/uc_server/` to do these

- `http://DOMAIN.DOM/uc_server/admin.php/uc_server/ ===changes to===> http://DOMAIN.DOM/uc_server/`
- if there is `...../install/index.php/....` in any requested links ;the `/install/index.php/` part would be omitted and the link would processed without that part.

Comment: this is my VHOST config file
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1480e0e8f2e58ae5b29a

Comment: the best way is to create a `location` block for `/uc_server` and do the return or rewrite there. But how?